# Why is Cognito signup showing ??phone_number/email_en_US?? as the username input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Does anyone know how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is the hosted GUI for cognito. Can you try opening it in another browser? And can inspect element and check if there are any errors in console?

Comment: I'm not sure what it was, I just took out the phone number as an option for username. And I'm not going to mess with this stack anymore right now but thank you for looking at this.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad This is the hosted Cognito GUI and it's also create from CloudFormation. I'm imagining there are other properties to be set in a particular way but the documentation is very, very unclear in this area.

Comment: My assumption is that if you add `phone_number` and `email` as standard attributes for the `UserPool`, that it will have the info for those fields to use for rendering in the hosted GUI, but I don't have time to play with all of the CloudFormation stack updates to really figure out how that works.

Comment: I will be looking to support phone numbers and SMS MFA eventually, so I guess I will come back around to this after some other features I have to get through now :)

Comment: We're also seeing this on a new cognito pool that allows signup via email or phone number. I'll try changing the pool to be email only (no phone number) to see if the visible locale info disapears

Comment: Can you upload or link your CloudFormation template?

Comment: @PatMyron It's here: https://github.com/resistdesign/rdx-cloudformation-assets/blob/master/RDX-With-CloudFront-And-Lambda-API-And-Cognito.yaml

Custom resource files are here: https://github.com/resistdesign/rdx-cloudformation-assets/tree/master/deploy

Comment: Here are some notes on the Cognito deploy: https://github.com/resistdesign/rdx-cloudformation-assets#notes-for-rdx-with-cloudfront-and-lambda-api-and-cognitoyaml

Comment: Also, I have since adjusted the template and removed the problematic sign-up fields, but essentially, when you add the phone as a login option, I think that's when it goes wrong.